# Add scrollbar to RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this RadioButtonList which contains a lot of items, so I need to add a vertical scrollbar. This is the code I add items to the RadioButtonList

```
    var Meals = Factory.Meals.List();
    var MealVotes = Factory.MealVotes.List(item => item.VoteDate == DateTime.Today);
    var MealVote = Factory.MealVotes.List(item => item.VoteDate == DateTime.Today && item.UserId == Instance.CurrentUserId).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var meal in Meals)
        {
            mealVotes = 0;
            TotalVotes = 0;

            foreach (var mealVote in MealVotes)
            {
                if (meal.Id == mealVote.MealId)
                {
                    mealVotes++;
                }

                TotalVotes++;
            }

            if (TotalVotes > 0)
            {
                Width = (100M / TotalVotes) * mealVotes;
            };

            VoteMealRadioButtonList.Items.Add(
                new ListItem(
                    meal.Title + " " + mealVotes +
                    @"<div style=""height: 10px; width:130px;"">" +
                        @"<a style=""float: left; width: 30px""></a>" +
                        @"<div style=""float: left; height: 10px; width:" + Width + @"px; background: DarkCyan;""></div>" +
                    "</div>",
                    meal.Id.ToString()
                )
            );
        }

        VoteMealRadioButtonList.SelectedValue = MealVote.MealId.ToString();
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Don't worry about the lists and meal names (which are in my native language). It wouldn't be a problem if the List would be filled with this amount of meals, but there will be 50 meals or something like that, so that's why I want to add a vertical scrollbar.

Is there anyway I can add a Scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put radiobuttonlist into a div and add scroll bar to this div ?

Comment: RadioButtonList was in div already. I didn't realize I can put scroll into the div first. Thanks, it's solved now :)